# How to add video frame by frame scrubber in iOS when I import video?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

I am looking to build a video editing application and I would like to include a frame by frame scrubber (as seen on the top of my screenshot) when user chooses a video with UIImagePickerController.  How can I use just the scrubber and then a custom sized preview (not full screen as shown here).

So far I was able to find this library: https://github.com/jaminschubert/JSVideoScrubber

However it doesn't look as good as apple's native scrubber.

Here is a sample image of how Apple's scrubber looks:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSiw1.jpg

Answer (score -4):

Here's [a link](https://github.com/jaminschubert/JSVideoScrubber).It'll help you.
https://github.com/jaminschubert/JSVideoScrubber

Comment: That's the same link already mentioned in the question. Can you find something better?